# Integrate VSLAM with Atlas in DRCsim

Tags: ros, gazebo, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to using DRCSIM and Atlas, but through tutorials, I was able to get through the basics of configuring rviz, gazebo,and the worlds for the bot.

Suppose I want to VSLAM with the Atlas in drcsim, in the world present in gazebo, can you please give me directions as to where I should start and how I can achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213551/integrate-vslam-with-atlas-in-drcsim/) by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simulated cameras of Atlas in DRCsim honor the ROS conventions for interfacing Cameras (e.g. they publish both Image and CameraInfo with same timestamp etc.). You should thus be able to take any VSLAM approach using these standard interfaces, remap the two topics in the VLSAM system's launch file and be good to go. Depending on the amount of features in your simulated world and other factors, you'll get good or not so good results :)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on 2015-07-13**:
Thanks a lot for the answer. It was really valuable. Could you please suggest me some good VSLAM package I can use to achieve the same?

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on 2015-07-14**:
I am using Ros Indigo by the way